# Feeding a list into a tabular with listofitems

Tags: tables, comma-separated-list

I am using [`listofitems`](https://ctan.org/pkg/listofitems) package to parse a list. Then I want to feed the result into a table (with particular details depending on the items indices). As the first step, I tried to just iterate over this list and write `A &` for each item `A`, but this produces an `Undefined control sequence` error message. Below is the minimal (non)-working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\begin{document}

\readlist\list{a,b,c,d}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
\foreachitem \listitem \in \list {\listitem &} & z
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Deleting `&` in `\listitem &` compiles and produces `abcd   z` as expected. So I would guess this is some sort of expansion problem. How can I work this around?

Suggestions for using other packages are also appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\foreachitem` loop is started in a cell of the `tabular` and ends in another, which is not possible.

My suggestion is to use `expl3`, which is straightforward

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definelist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_clear_new:c { l_smolensky_list_#1_clist }
  \clist_set:cn { l_smolensky_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\uselist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_use:cn { l_smolensky_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\uselistsize}{m}
 {
  \clist_count:c { l_smolensky_list_#1_clist }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definelist{list}{a,b,c,d}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{\uselistsize{list}}{c}c}
\uselist{list}{&} & z
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The items will be separated by the tokens in the second mandatory argument to `\uselist`. I also added `\uselistsize` to show a possible use case.

[image]

The difference with `\foreachitem` is that `\clist_use:cn` will generate the tokens “all at once”, so the `&` tokens will only be seen when the command `\clist_use:cn` has already done its complete work and there is no problem of overlapping cells.

---

You can also use `listofitems`, if you so prefer:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\def\foreachitemdeliver#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \def\foreachitemdeliverpartial{}%
  \def\foreachitemdeliveraction##1{#2}%
  \foreachitem\foreachitemitem\in#1{%
    \edef\foreachitemdeliverpartial{%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\foreachitemdeliverpartial}%
      \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\foreachitemdeliveraction\expandafter{\foreachitemitem}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \expandafter\endgroup\foreachitemdeliverpartial
}

\begin{document}

\readlist\list{a,b,c,d}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
\foreachitemdeliver\list{#1 &} z
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks very nice! Unfortunately, it will present a problem for arXiv of journal submission :(

Comment: @AndreiSmolensky Add `\usepackage{xparse}`.

Comment: @AndreiSmolensky I added also an implementation with `listofitems`. Some `\expandafter` trickery. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `listofitems`, but answering about your "suggestions for using other packages" I can recommend looking into [`pgfplotstable`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) that is coming from the PGF/TikZ corner of CTAN. Chapter 3 in the user manual covers your use case (reading table data, producing a typeset `tabular`).

[image: rendered tabular environment generated by pgfplotstable]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={date,account3,account2,account1},
    column type={r},
    columns/date/.style={date type={\monthname\ \year}},
    columns/account1/.style={fonts by sign={}{\color{red}}},
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
]{
    date    account1    account2    account3
    2008-01-03    60  1200  400
    2008-02-06    120 1600 410
    2008-03-15    -10 1600 410
    2008-04-0 11800   500    410
    2008-05-20    2300    500 410
    2008-06-15    800 1920 410
}
\hspace{1em}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    string type,
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
]{%
    a,b,c,d,e
    d,e,f,f,g
}

\end{document}
```